# Jmeter summary report issue

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0

I am running the performance test in jmeter. in the summary report std div values are showing 0.0 but at the total column it is showing 1855.88.[please check the std div column in below image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zi6T.png)

I am not understanding what is the issue in std div column if the values are 0.0 then total value should be 0.0 right?

Answer (score 0):

1. Value of `0.0`: you have executed each Sampler **only once**, there is no "deviation" in response times because there is **only one result**. If you run your test with 2 iterations you will see "deviation" values

   [image]
2. Value of `1855.88` is the deviation for **ALL** executed Samplers, you have 25 total requests with different response times and the deviation reflects the difference in them.

More information:

- [Standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation)
- [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html)
- [Request Stats Report](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000303837-Request-Stats-Report)